# Subtratc row with previous one when two conditions are met

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need help creating a dataframe that subtracts the row with the previous with 3 conditions to be met:

If the column Same Driver is FALSE then the result column interval shold be 0

If the column Same Driver is TRUE and the column Same Trip is also TRUE the result should be 0

If the column Same Driver is TRUE but the column Same Trip is FALSE then it should be applied `df['Interval'] = df['Data']-df['Data'].shift()`

```
import pandas as pd

date = ["04/04/2021","01/04/2021","11/04/2021","11/04/2021","15/04/2021","15/04/2021","07/04/2021","09/04/2021","09/04/2021"]

date = pd.to_datetime(date, dayfirst=True)
df_date = pd.DataFrame(date, columns=['Data'])

df = pd.DataFrame({
          'Same Driver': [False,False,True,True,True,True,False,True,True],
          'Same Trip': [False,False,True,True,False,True,False,False,True],
          'Desired Interval': [0,0,0,0,4,0,0,2,0]
          })

df = pd.concat([df,df_date],axis=1)

df['Interval'] = df['Data']-df['Data'].shift()
```

You can see the desired output in the column Desired Interval

Answer (score 0):

Let's try something like:

```py
import pandas as pd

date = ["04/04/2021", "01/04/2021", "11/04/2021",
        "11/04/2021", "15/04/2021", "15/04/2021",
        "07/04/2021", "09/04/2021", "09/04/2021"]

date = pd.to_datetime(date, dayfirst=True)
df_date = pd.DataFrame(date, columns=['Data'])

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Same Driver': [False, False, True, True, True, True, False, True, True],
    'Same Trip': [False, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, True]
})

df = pd.concat([df, df_date], axis=1)
g = df.groupby(
    # Delimit Groups by True False Rows
    (df['Same Driver'] & ~df['Same Trip'])
        .cumsum()
        .shift()  # Shift So that last row is in next group
        .fillna(0)
)
# Set Rows equal to size of previous group (-1 to counter the previous shift)
df.loc[g.apply(pd.DataFrame.last_valid_index), 'Interval'] = g.size().values - 1
# Fill Na with 0 and convert back to int
df['Interval'] = df['Interval'].fillna(0).astype(int)

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

Output:

```
Same Driver  Same Trip       Data  Interval
      False      False 2021-04-04         0
      False      False 2021-04-01         0
       True       True 2021-04-11         0
       True       True 2021-04-11         0
       True      False 2021-04-15         4
       True       True 2021-04-15         0
      False      False 2021-04-07         0
       True      False 2021-04-09         2
       True       True 2021-04-09         0
```